# Will I be able to recover win 10 license after removing microsoft account?

Tags: windows, windows-10, license, microsoft-account, windows-10-pro

I just activated a Windows 10 Pro license in a new computer, and a friend convinced me to link my microsoft account to my windows installation so I will be able to reactivate it after a hardware change.

The account linking worked fine and now my device shows up on https://account.microsoft.com/devices/

But windows started asking me to setup windows hello, mail, etc, and didn't want to, so I removed the microsoft account & email from my windows installation, so I could login into my pc using my local account.

The device still shows up on https://account.microsoft.com/devices/

My question is, if I need to reactivate my windows license in the future, will I be able to do it using my microsoft account even if I removed if from my windows installation?

Comment: No you do not need to re-activate. Activation does not depend on a Microsoft Account. I have 1 machine local and is activated. I have two machines that were local and activated and then I switched to Microsoft Account on both of these. Activation not affected on any machine. If you need to reactivate for some reason, again it does not depend on the type of account.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You don't need Microsoft account to activate windows.